# Why does EF want to create indexes after database restore?

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-2008, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

After restoring a database from 1 server to another, I get an [`AutomaticMigrationsDisabledException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.infrastructure.automaticmigrationsdisabledexception%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) from EF saying that the database does match the current model although they actually do match.

So I try to generate a migration from VS and it only contains a bunch of [`CreateIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh829515%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) statements for which there already are indexes in the database. And sure enough, when I execute the migration, I get an error.

I previously restored the exact same database to yet another server without any problems. However, the servers are not completely identical. They are all SQL Server 2008, but some have different combinations of SP and KB applied to them.

I'm using EF 6.1.

Can you figure out what the problem is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a bug in version 6.1, will be fixed in 6.1.1 - https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2167